# df.loc[df.loc[:,'Col1'].str.contains('_id'),'Col2']='stringValue'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a boolean mask against a dataframe that works for me:

```
df.loc[df.loc[:,'Col1'].str.contains('_id'),'Col2']='stringValue'
```

but get the error

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:141: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

I have researched this and can not come up with a way to write it without getting this error any help?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the way you wrote it. It's what you did before. df is a slice of another dataframe so all changes to it will trigger this warning. Set `df.is_copy = None` before this assignment and the warning will disappear.

Comment: Yes it did and Thank You